# PySpark - How to 'sc.parallelize' a function that yields a generator (Pickling Error)?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

My specific use case is quite different, but this simple example is able to replicate my issue.

```
def foo(inp):
  yield 2*inp
  
def bar(result):
  x = next(result)
  return x

inp = range(0,10000)
results = []
for f in inp:
  results.append(foo(f))
  
rdd_sim = sc.parallelize(results, numSlices=4)
results = rdd_sim.map(lambda x: bar(x)).collect()
```

Here I have a function that yields a gen object. The gen object is then used as an input to the function bar. I'm trying to parallelize this entire process but am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot pickle 'generator' object
```

Due to memory considerations, a generator is more appropriate for my use case, so would appreciate any ideas here.

Comment: You are trying to mix python semantics with spark's way of doing things. In spark, all the input data is ingested upfront and then transformations are applied on it. Can you tell in plain language what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: yes, I have a function that sends get requests to a server and parses the response. Again, memory may be an issue which is why I'd like to avoid 'returning' all my responses.

Comment: If you are worried about memory, you can always spill data to disk. Alternatively, You can partition data into N chunks and process those chunks sequentially if you worred about resource constraints. Or you can use a Structured Streaming semantics and set batch size.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix python's optimization and way of thinking with Spark's way of doing things. If `result` is going to be list, there are other ways to achieve the same thing without `next`. Search for Window functions.

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from itertools import chain

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


def foo(inp):
    yield 2 * inp


def bar(result):
    x = next(result)
    return x

def spark_foo(inp):
    return 2 * inp


def spark_bar(result):
    x = result
    return x

inp = range(0, 10)

results = []
for f in inp:
    results.append(f)




rdd_sim = sc.parallelize(results, numSlices=4)
rdd_sim_spark = rdd_sim.map(lambda x:spark_bar(spark_foo(x))).collect()
print("Spark version")
print(rdd_sim_spark)

## What you are trying to achieve in spark.
inp = range(0, 10)
results_old = []
for f in inp:
    results_old.append(f)

final_results_old = list(map((lambda x: bar(foo(x))), results_old))
print("What you are trying to achieve")
print(final_results_old)
```

Output  :

```
Spark version
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
What you are trying to achieve
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```